# running commands for different files and storing output results

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have a lot of files in my computer and I need to run a program with some commands in order to evaluate this files and get some results. The commands for evaluating one of the files are something like this:

```
./abc
abc 01> read_verilog myfile1.v
abc 02> sat
abc 03> quit
```

after running the "sat" command, some results will be shown in the terminal and I need to store them in a .txt file.
I have written a script to run this commands (below) for 1000 files but my problem is that I cannot store the output of "sat" command for all of these files.

```
  #!/bin/bash
# since Bash v4
for i in {1..1000..1}
do
    ./abc <<EOF
    read_verilog "myfile$i.v"
    sat
    quit
    EOF
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the output of here-doc to a target output file as below

```
./abc <<EOF > /tmp/outputfile"${i}".txt
read_verilog "myfile$i.v"
sat
quit
EOF
```

The target output path can be anything, not essentially be under `/tmp`, could just be `outputfile"${i}".txt`